# Commerce as a Service with REST

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, saas

I was searching all over the web for a decent answer to this question and ended up back here at SO.  I am developing a mobile app which sells digital goods.  I don't want to set up a backend & frontend just manage all the goods.  What I am looking for is a very basic SaaS solution to manage promotions, products, collections and metadata and retrieve these through an API.  Ideally the API provides a basic search functionality.  To me, this seems like it should be a solved problem but the only solution I can think of is Shopify Storefront API + Firebase Cloud Functions for the checkout flow.  What are good approaches for tackling this problem?